# Group by sum and find min max of date from the group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table as below.

```
                                           msno      date  num_25  num_50  num_75  num_985  num_100  num_unq
1  PNxIsSLWOJDCm7pNPFzRO/6Mmg2WeZA2nf6hw6t1x3g=  20151201       3       3       2        0        8       11   
2  PNxIsSLWOJDCm7pNPFzRO/6Mmg2WeZA2nf6hw6t1x3g=  20160628       0       0       1        1        1        3   
3  PNxIsSLWOJDCm7pNPFzRO/6Mmg2WeZA2nf6hw6t1x3g=  20170106       2       1       0        0       35       34
4  KXF9c/T66LZIzFq+xS64icWMhDQE6miCZAtdXRjZHX8=  20150803       0       0       0        0       16       11   
5  KXF9c/T66LZIzFq+xS64icWMhDQE6miCZAtdXRjZHX8=  20160527       4       3       0        2        2       11   
6  KXF9c/T66LZIzFq+xS64icWMhDQE6miCZAtdXRjZHX8=  20160808      14       3       4        1       15       31
```

I wish to group them up by summing up the num_(25 until unq) and then determine the earliest date and latest date occur in the identical msno.

```
df = df_user_logs_v2.drop('date', axis=1).groupby('msno', as_index=False).sum()
```

The code above can sum up all the values but the date have to be dropped. I wish to retain the min and max of the date, along with number of row count.

Expected Output for the first msno:

```
                                          msno  num_25_sum  num_50_sum  num_75_sum  num_985_sum  num_100_sum  num_unq_sum date_earliest date_latest count
1 PNxIsSLWOJDCm7pNPFzRO/6Mmg2WeZA2nf6hw6t1x3g=           5           4           3            1           44           48      20151201    20170106     3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
d = dict((i,'sum') for i in df.columns[2:])
d['date'] = ['min','max']
d['msno'] = 'count'
df_out = df.groupby('msno').agg(d)
df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map('_'.join)

df_out
```

Output:

```
                                              msno_count  date_min  date_max  \
msno                                                                           
KXF9c/T66LZIzFq+xS64icWMhDQE6miCZAtdXRjZHX8=           3  20150803  20160808   
PNxIsSLWOJDCm7pNPFzRO/6Mmg2WeZA2nf6hw6t1x3g=           3  20151201  20170106   

                                              num_75_sum  num_50_sum  \
msno                                                                   
KXF9c/T66LZIzFq+xS64icWMhDQE6miCZAtdXRjZHX8=           4           6   
PNxIsSLWOJDCm7pNPFzRO/6Mmg2WeZA2nf6hw6t1x3g=           3           4   

                                              num_985_sum  num_25_sum  \
msno                                                                    
KXF9c/T66LZIzFq+xS64icWMhDQE6miCZAtdXRjZHX8=            3          18   
PNxIsSLWOJDCm7pNPFzRO/6Mmg2WeZA2nf6hw6t1x3g=            1           5   

                                              num_100_sum  num_unq_sum  
msno                                                                    
KXF9c/T66LZIzFq+xS64icWMhDQE6miCZAtdXRjZHX8=           33           53  
PNxIsSLWOJDCm7pNPFzRO/6Mmg2WeZA2nf6hw6t1x3g=           44           48
```

[image]